# Fraction of fibers that have failed

Tags: distributions, homework

I have the following to set into mathematica.

Assume a stress(sigma) applied on a specimen which has a number of fibers within it. All fibers that have a strength less than the applied stress should fail. I set a cumulative distribution of the fiber strengths with a mean and standard deviation.

I want to use this cumulative distribution to tell me how many fibers are less than the applied stress which have failed and store this number somewhere. This procedure should be repeated until all fibers have failed. so there is a convergence in the two variables. I am new in mathematica so sorry for a vague question.

thanks,

Nick

Comment: @blochwave. So far I have only trying to see how I should write it in mathematica but nothing in code yet

Comment: I guess you want to loop until all fibers are gone. Keep them ordered by strength. Each iteration, select a random value from your probability distribution. If it exceeds the lowest remaining strength, remove fibers from there on until hitting one of adequate strength. Rinse, repeat.

Comment: Assume you are doing a simulation by generating a numerical list of strengths use `Select`.  (You can do this analytically as well using `CDF` clarify if thats what you mean. )

Comment: @george2079 is it possible to put a normal distribution in the `list` from the `select` command?

Comment: trying to give hints where to look in the docs.. the other thing you need is `RandomVariate`..

Answer (score 3):

Here's an implementation showing the load-carrying capacity of the bundle of fibers as the weakest remaining fiber breaks:

```
nFibers = 1000;
mean = 100;
stdev = 20;
fibers = Sort@Abs@RandomVariate[NormalDistribution[mean, stdev], nFibers];
pull[{load_, fibers_}] := {
  First@fibers*Length@fibers,(* load just before weakest fiber breaks *)
  Rest@fibers(* remaining fibers after weakest fiber breaks *)
}
ListPlot[First@Transpose@NestList[pull, {0, fibers}, nFibers], Joined -> True]
```

[image]

The NestList command iteratively applies the 'pull' function, producing a sequence of the fiber bundle's load-carrying capacity as each successive fiber breaks.

Comment: interesting approach. Note since you sorted the fibers it could be `First@` instead of `Min@`

Comment: That's a good point.  I'll change it to `First@`.

Answer (score 1):

Here is how you do this analytically: (using  user2790167's `pull` in pure function form)

```
 nFibers = 50;
 mean = 100;
 stdev = 20;
 fibers = Sort@RandomVariate[NormalDistribution[mean, stdev], nFibers];
 Show[{
      Plot[  InverseCDF[ NormalDistribution[ mean, stdev] , nweak/nFibers] 
         (nFibers - nweak + 1 ), {nweak, 1, nFibers - 1}, PlotStyle -> {Red, Dashed}],
      ListPlot[
         Rest@First@
            Transpose@
              NestList[{First@#[[2]] Length@#[[2]], Rest@#[[2]]} &,
                  {0, fibers}, nFibers], Joined -> True, 
          AxesLabel -> {"Broken Fibers", "Net Load"}]}, PlotRange -> All, 
          AxesOrigin -> {0, 0}]
```

[image]

Also it is useful to plot against the strength of the fiber that is about to fail:
(which correlates to strain assuming equal stiffness of the fibers )

```
 nFibers = 50;
 mean = 100;
 stdev = 20;
 fibers = Sort@RandomVariate[NormalDistribution[mean, stdev], nFibers];
 Show[{
   Plot[  s  (nFibers (1 - CDF[ NormalDistribution[ mean, stdev] , s]) ) ,
       {s, 0, 200}, PlotStyle -> {Red, Dashed}],
   ListPlot[
     First@
        Transpose@
           NestList[{{First@#[[2]] {1, Length@#[[2]]}, Rest@#[[2]]} &, 
             {{0, 0}, fibers}, nFibers], Joined -> True, 
           AxesLabel -> {"min surviving strength", "Net Load"}]}, PlotRange -> All, 
           AxesOrigin -> {0, 0}, AspectRatio -> 1/GoldenRatio]
```

[image]

for large nFibers the simulations converge to the analytic form..